# How to get badge info using the stackr library for the API?

Tags: r, stackexchange-api

I would like to use the Stack Exchange API with a specific user id to get the text of a user's badges.

I found [the *stackr* library for the Stack Exchange API](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr), and tried this:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/stackr")
library(stackr)
stack_users(712603)
```

But that only gives the total number of every kind of badge. How can I take the text from each one?
Example:

```
gold silver bronze
r     r      ggplot2
```

I don't only want the total number of badges but also what the badges are.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking?  And please fix your spelling throughout.  I can't tell if you want to get a single user and see what badges they have, or find all users with a specific badge.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel thank you. As I mention at the start I want for a single user. For example user has 6 gold badges which could be r, python etc.

Comment: @BrockAdams thank you I tried it but it gives only some of bronze badges

Comment: You probably aren't paging through the results.  Consult the docs for that library.

Comment: @BrockAdams thank you. Unfortunately I can't find an official document and using in r console `?stack_users` I can't see any paging through the results.

Comment: @BrockAdams thank you it was very helpful for me. Please could you help with one more thing. I would like to take all questions of a user with their body. I tried this `textques <- stack_users(712603, "questions", body = "true", num_pages=10, pagesize=100)` but it hasn't the body. Any idea if it is possible to take also the body?

Comment: @BrockAdams many thanks I made it. I agree totally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that library, use:

```
stack_users(712603, "badges")
```

to get badges with descriptions and use something like:

```
stack_users(712603, "badges", num_pages=10, pagesize=100)
```

to get the user's first<sup>†</sup> 1000 badges.

---

<sup>†</sup> The default ordering is by *rank*, not date, so you would get bronze badges first, then silver, then gold, with that library.